# free(): invalid next size (normal) with qsort()

Tags: c

When running this code for seeds dataset of size 210*8, I am getting an error after the qsort() line in predict function. It is not executing after the qsort().

I am not sure if qsort is causing this error or why it occurs but any insight would be appreciated.

I get an error when the qsort statement is executed.

My Code:

```
`include stdio.h
    include stdlib.h
    include string.h
    include math.h

    typedef struct point{
        int class;
        float coords[7], dist;
    }point;

    int argmax(int arr[], int n){
        int marg = -1, mxf = -1, i;
        for (i =0; i<= n; i++){
            if (arr[i] > mxf){
                mxf = arr[i];
                marg = i;
            }
        }
        return marg;
    }

    float get_accuracy(int pred[], int act[], int n){
        float cor = 0;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i< n; i++){
            if (pred[i] == act[i]) cor +=1;
        }
        return (cor*100.0)/n ;
    }

    float get_avg(float arr[], int n){
        float sum = 0;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i<n; i++){
            sum +=  arr[i];
        }
        return sum/n;
    }

    point *shuffle(point *dataset, int rows, int features, int groups, int classes)
    {
        int i,j,k,l,m = 0;
        point *shuffled_dataset;
        shuffled_dataset = (point *)malloc(sizeof(point)*rows);
        for(i=0; i<rows/classes; i++,m++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<rows/(groups*classes); j++)
            {
                for(k=0; k<classes; k++,m++)
                {
                    shuffled_dataset[m] = dataset[rows/classes*k + i];
                    /*for(l=0; l<features; l++)
                    {
                        shuffled_dataset[m].coords[l] = dataset[rows/classes*k + i].coords[l];
                    }*/
                }
                i++;
            }
            i--;
        }
        return shuffled_dataset;
    }


    float minkowski_dist(float* x, float* y, int len, int p){
        int i;
        float sum=0;
        for(i=0;i < len; i++){
            sum += pow(fabs(x[i] - y[i]),p);
        }
        return pow(sum,1/p);
    }

    int comparison(const void *a, const void *b) {
        point *ia = (point *)a;
        point *ib = (point *)b;
        return (int)(100.f*ia->dist - 100.f*ib->dist);
    }

    int predict(point test_point, point train[], int n, int k, int p, int classes, int features){
        int i;
        printf("Hi\n");
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            train[i].dist = minkowski_dist(test_point.coords, train[i].coords, features, p);
            printf("%d.\t", i+1);
            print_point(train[i]);
        }
        qsort (train, n-1, sizeof(train[0]), comparison);
        int freq[classes+1];
        for (i = 0; i < classes+1; ++i)
            freq[i] = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < k; i++)  
           freq[train[i].class]++; 
        return argmax(freq,classes);
    }

    float rFoldKNN(point *arr, int num, int r, int k, int p,  int classes, int features){
        int gsize = num/r;
        int i, j, h;
        int pred[gsize], act[gsize];
        point cval[gsize], train[num - gsize];
        float acc[r];
        for(i=0; i<r; i++)
        {
            int cind = 0, tind = 0;
            for(j=0; j<gsize; j++)
            {
                cval[cind++] = arr[gsize*i+j];
                for(k=0; k<r; k++)
                {
                    if(k!=i)
                    {
                        train[tind++] = arr[gsize*k+j];
                    }
                }
            }
            for(j=0; j<gsize; j++)
            {
                printf("%d\t%d\n", tind, cind);
                pred[j] = predict(cval[j], train,  num-gsize, k,  p, classes, features);
                act[j] = cval[j].class;
            }
            acc[i] = get_accuracy(pred, act,  gsize);
        }
        return get_avg(acc,r);
    }

    int main()
    {
        FILE *fp;
        int r = 10, p = 5, k = 10;
        int rows = 210;
        int columns = 8;
        int classes = 3;
        int size = rows * columns; /*Assumed size of the dataset*/
        float *data;          /*Creating an array of assumed size as 1d(split after every 8 values to get the next row)*/
        int count = 0;
        int i, j;
        float accuracies [k][p], maxac = -1.0;;
        int maxk, maxp;
        float c;
        point *all;
        all = (point *)malloc(sizeof(point)*rows);
        data = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float*)*size);
        if ((fp = fopen("seeds_dataset.txt", "r")) == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error reading file!");
            exit(1);
        }
        for(i = 0; i < rows; i++){
            for (j = 0 ; j < columns; j++){
                fscanf(fp,"%f",&c);
                if (j == columns-1)
                    all[i].class = c;
                else
                    all[i].coords[j] = c;
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);
        for(i=0; i<rows; i++)
        {
            printf("%d.\t", i+1);
            print_point(all[i]);
        }
        all = shuffle(all, rows, columns-1, 10, classes);
        printf("Hi\n");
        for(i=0; i<rows; i++)
        {
            printf("%d.\t", i+1);
            print_point(all[i]);
        }
        for (i = 1; i <= k; ++i){
            for (j = 1; j <= p; ++j){
                accuracies[i][j] = rFoldKNN(all, rows, r, i, j, classes, columns-1);
                if (accuracies[i][j] > maxac){
                    maxac = accuracies[i][j];
                    maxk = i;
                    maxp = j;
                }
            }
        }
        printf("best validation accuracy %f  best k %d best p %d ",maxac, maxk, maxp );
        return 0;
    }

`
```

Comment: That's still not really a minimal example and it is not complete any more. Please remove every part of the code that is not needed to reproduce your problem. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for further reference

Comment: Removing code of called functions while the function calls are still in the sample, is not sufficient. Instead remove the call as well if you don't need it to cause the problem to occur.

Comment: [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

`free(): invalid next size` is the error message you frequently get when you have corrupted the memory arena used by `malloc`, such as writing beyond the end of an allocated block, destroying in-line accounting information used by the memory allocation functions.

Given the scarcity of actual *code* in your question (or, after your update, the huge *volume* of code which you appear not to have slimmed down to more accurately pinpoint the problem), that's about as much detail as I can provide. My suggestion is to examine your code for areas where you don't properly use allocated memory.

Comment: I have added my code now. Could you see what the mistake could be?

Comment: @VismithAdappa. I *could* do that. Or you could. At a bare minimum, it would be prudent to provide a minimalistic code sample that still exhibits the problem. Often, when you do that, you find the actual problem yourself. I'm not overly keen on trolling through such a massive program, especially since you will become a better developer by learning to do it yourself (and because what you have posted won't compile as-is).

Comment: The error occurs when the qsort() in predict() executes but I don't know why.